# Calling a both Shell Script and a Korn script in a Korn Script

Tags: sh, ksh

I am trying to call both a korn shell and a shell script at the same time. In a ksh. My ksh script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

. /u01/EPM/hyp_app/scripts/maxl/Start_Stop/Stop_All.ksh
. /app/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem1/bin/stop.sh
```

This will successfully run the .sh, but will unsuccessfully run the .ksh, and return this error

```
/u01/EPM/hyp_app/scripts/maxl/Start_Stop/Stop_All.ksh: line 33: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
/u01/EPM/hyp_app/scripts/maxl/Start_Stop/Stop_All.ksh: line 33: `if [ $f1 != ' ' ]; then;'
```

But when running that Stop_All.ksh by itself, it works fine with no issues.

Why is it a syntax error when run from someplace else, but not a syntax error when run directly? Note the location of this bigger ksh is in the same location as the Stop_All.ksh. So it's not a relative directory issue (i don't think).

Edit:

Part of the problem is that the text files in the Stop_All.ksh are not being create when run as part of the greater script (but creates it no problem when I run it by itself).

```
#Clears database log
echo ' ' > /u01/EPM/hyp_app/logs/Start_Stop/DatabaseList.log

# run filter export process
$ESS_ENV_DIR/startMaxl.sh $SCRIPT_DIR/maxl/Start_Stop/SpoolDatabase.mxl

echo ' ' > /u01/EPM/hyp_app/export/Start_Stop/Application_List.txt

# Parses it out in do 8 for start and stop, and insert | pipe
sed -i -e 's/./&|/21' -i -e 's/./&|/30' -i -e 's/./&|/40'  /u01/EPM/hyp_app/logs/Start_Stop/DatabaseList.log;
cat /u01/EPM/hyp_app/logs/Start_Stop/DatabaseList.log | grep 'TRUE' > /u01/EPM/hyp_app/export/Start_Stop/GrepApplication_List.txt
while IFS='|' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 #f5
do echo $f1 $f2 >> /u01/EPM/hyp_app/export/Start_Stop/Application_List.txt
echo $f3 >> /u01/EPM/hyp_app/export/Start_Stop/Application_List.txt

# finishes do while and the points the input file that the IFS reads through (PUT DATABSE TXT FILE HERE)
done < /u01/EPM/hyp_app/export/Start_Stop/GrepApplication_List.txt;
while IFS=' ' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 #f5
do 

 if [ $f1 != ' ' ]; then;
   $ESS_ENV_DIR/startMaxl.sh $SCRIPT_DIR/maxl/Start_Stop/Master_Stop.mxl $f1 $f2
    fi
```

Comment: To be clear, your outer script is not korn shell. The header is set to #!/bin/sh.

Comment: well the outer one was set to a .ksh. Likewise, all of our ksh's begin with this line of code, i believe the # makes it so that it is commented out, but not 100% sure.

Comment: No, the file extension is not important. When the first line begins with #! (Called a shebang) is not a fomment, it tells Linus how to execute the file.

Comment: huh, so despite being a ksh it's still technically a .sh?

I've added the code of the Stop_All.ksh, I thought the syntax used is korn shell, could i just change this script to a .sh?

Comment: Change the shebang to #!/bin/ksh

Comment: wow that totally worked!, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you test `if [ $f1 != ' ' ];` you are expecting that `f1` can be a space. Suppose `f1` is filled with a space. The line `if [   != ' ' ];` is an error.
I think that when you were running Stop_All.ksh by itself, `f1` was filled with something else than a space.
Change your code into

```
if [ "$f1" != ' ' ];
```

or get used to the syntax with curly braces

```
if [ "${f1}" != ' ' ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, part of the code is reading in from text files that are created earlier in the script. However, running this script seems to not be create those files when it is not run by itself

Comment: edit: I've added more detail about the innter script in my original post. The text files aren't being created

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user Nick Burns,

I had to change the top to #!/bin/ksh